# Match first occurrence of element backwards in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I've a page with some forms. On submission, I would like to match the first occurrence of an element (i.e. a paragraph) searching backwards the form. For example

- on `#firstform` submission I would like to match the
  `#secondparagraph`
- on `#secondform` submission I would like to match
  the `#thirdparagraph`

```
<div>
  <p id="firstparagraph">Some other paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>First element</li>
    <li>Second element</li>
  </ul>
  <p id="secondparagraph">Some other paragraph</p>
</div>

<form id="firstform">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit1" />
</form>

<p id="thirdparagraph">Some other paragraph</p>

<form id="secondform">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit2" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to create a jQuery function that searches backwards and stops on the first matching occurrence?

Comment: This is not a trivial problem to solve as you require recursively looking through sibling elements of the form to look for the `p` tag you want. Can you post the code you've attempted to write yourself to fix this issue.

Comment: Does the `<div>` have to be there? It makes the code a lot more difficult. If the `<div>` wasn't there, it'd be as simple as `$('form').on('submit', function () { var paragraph = $(this).prevAll('p').first(); });`

Comment: it depends much on the HTML structure, in general case I think the code is not simple.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Actually I don't have clue about a possible code. I've found some jQuery functions like prevAll or reverse, but each of them seems to search on siblings only. I'm perfectly conscious that it's not a trivial problem, because I would like to find the first occurrence independently of HTML structure. I know it's a very general problem, thus very difficult.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why is your structure so random?

Comment: Could you give all the relevant elements a class? If both the element you're starting from and the elements you want to search for have the same class, it becomes much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var p = $(this).parents().addBack().prevAll().find('p').addBack('p').last();
```

[demonstration](http://jsbin.com/hepawefuxi/edit?html,js,output)

The idea is to make a collection from the previous sibblings of all parents, and search for the last paragraph in this (big) collection.

Comment: I think it's a very clever solution. Of course this assumes a deep knowledge of jQuery I actually don't have. Just let me think a while about it (it's quite complex for me to analyse the result of each command on the chain), but I think it may be the best, since it's very general.

Comment: ``addBack()`` is now ``andSelf()`` in jQuery >= 1.8: https://api.jquery.com/andSelf/ https://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Comment: @WesTurner The not deprecated one is `addBack`, which is used in this answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's still ``andSelf`` in the demonstration

Comment: @WesTurner Oh thanks, I understand your comment now. I edited the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I think jQuery traverses the elements in the order we read the code, so you can try this code, for the demo, I've even added some nested `p` elements, but it may not be your case. This works for any HTML structure you have:

```
var token = 'abd432432efdfsdfe42342398kjkfljsdlkfjs';
$('input').click(function(e){
  $(this).wrap($("<p>").attr('id',token));
  var p;
  $('p[id]').each(function(i){        
    if($(this).attr('id') == token) return false;        
    p = $(this);
  });
  $(this).unwrap();
  //try showing the id of the matched p element
  alert(p.attr('id'));
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Wcw/5/)

We should search for only `p` elements having `id` attributes (or some other sign) because the browser sometimes insert some empty `p` element and hence unexpected result.

Comment: @Barmar thanks :) however it required some time to think out, even some time was lost because of unexpected result caused by the empty `p` elements (inserted automatically by browser).

Comment: @dystroy I don't know about the direct search you mean. If you mean searching the HTML text of the whole document, yes I thought of that way, I just liked this way using jQuery.

Comment: @dystroy ah, if the HTML structure is well-known beforehand, of course doing so is much simpler and ***more*** efficient. But I added this for a general solution in which the HTML structure does not matter (it can change, and the code still works).

Comment: My solution is general too, of couse.

Comment: @dystroy wow, I've looked closely to your code (not even looked into it before), in fact that way it works. The demo I edited was wrong.

Comment: @dystroy can't believe it, your code is much shorter and even much more efficient, I've made a jsperf here http://jsperf.com/demo1-vs-demo2 . I couldn't believe that my solution is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you were just looking for the last element of (type), the `:last` selector would be what you are looking for. It matches the last occurrence of an element. So

```
$("p:last")
```

Would get the last paragraph.

However the way I understand it, you want to get the last element BEFORE another element (in your case, the clicked submit button), there are a couple days to do it. I would use something like

```
$(myElement).prevAll('p:first');
```

You use a similar selector but now it is only affecting the DOM elements that come before your submit element (or whatever element you want to use). You use `:first` rather than `:last` because `prevAll()` gets the list of elements in reverse order.

[JSfiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/k2bak/)

Comment: `prevAll` only returns siblings of the given element. Look at his example, `#secondparagraph` is not a sibling of `#firstform`, it's a nephew.